# parse error when i build my first xamarin android app

Tags: android, xamarin, sdk

I am a unity developer and I built so many apps on android platform with **same sdk and jdk that I use in xamarin**, for having more capacities...
when I built first app by xamarin tutorials, I could debug it on my phone with usb debugging But when I archived the project, and tried to install it on phone, I face this Error:

> Parse error
>   There was a problem parsing the package."

I tried these ways but every time faced the same error:

- apply install permission
- apply all permissions to be sure nothing was missed
- download complete projects from xamarin site and github
- update android sdk(attached the screenshot of android sdk manager)
- googled the problem with many keywords

[image]

Comment: follow the [guide](http://www.technicalnotes.org/fix-parse-error-in-android-there-is-a-problem-parsing-the-package/). You may do something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your debug application was signed with debug certificate and when it was archived you generated a release certificate. In android you cannot update an application signed with different certificates. I suggest to uninstall the debug application.

Comment: thank you for the answer
as i mentioned i'm a beginner in xamarin...
can you say more specific
how can i unistall the debug app?

Comment: Go in Android Settings, applications then uninstall your app.